# Can someone check my calculation, if it's wrong can you explain where I went wrong. Thank you

Tags: solution-verification, percentages

$\text{Percentage decrease }= \dfrac{\text{actual decrease}}{\text{original value}} \times 100$

- Decrease between $2003$ and $2018 = 5.5 \cdot 10^6 \text{ km}^2 – 4.6 \cdot 10^6 \text{ km}^2 = 0.9 \cdot 10^6 \text{ km}^2$
- Percentage decrease $2003$ of $2018$ value $=\dfrac{ 0.9 \cdot 10^6 \text{ km}^2}{4.6 \cdot 10^6 \text{ km}^2} = 19.6\%$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you please use MathJax, or indicate with explicit notations what you mean by $5.5*106$ is it $5.5*10^6$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem definition is something like: "A quantity (area) has was equal to $5.5\cdot 10^6~\text{km}^2$ in 2003, and in 2018 it was only $4.6\cdot 10^6 \text{km}^2$. Calculate the percentage decrease."

Comment: I apologise I'm new to this website I don't know how to incorporate the subscript. It is 5.5 * 10 to the power of 6

Comment: It is to express the percentage of the acual value of 2018 to the nearest 1% of ice extent, area.

Comment: Write MathJax code and numbers inside dollar signs. To write an exponent, like $2^{10}$, type \$2^{10}\$. Axel's answer gives the correct computation. Your error is in the first line. $$5.5\times 10^6km^2 - 4.6\times 10^6km^2 = 0.9 \times 10^6km^2 \not = 9 \times 10^{-1}km^2$$

Comment: @Jade is my answer clear enough for you?

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is clear.

Comment: @Jade You're welcome. I suggested an edit of your post to make it clearer. And don't hesitate to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @DavidDiaz Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well I assume you are looking for the following:

The decrease of land between $2003$ and $2018$ is $5.5 \times 10^6 \text{ km}^2-4.6\times 10^6 \text{ km}^2=0.9\times10^6 \text{ km}^2$.

Therefore the percentage decrease is $(\frac{0.9\times 10^6}{5.5 \times 10^6}) =16.4\%$.

The percentage decrease is $\frac{\text{amount of decrease}}{\text{original value}} \times 100$ by definition.

Here your original value is the area of land in $2003$ that is $5.5\times 10^6 \text{ km}^2$